# Error checking ARR metadata when compiling Gradle project in Android Studio

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

When I try to compile a project, a Gradle error occurs. I tried to clear the Android Studio cache, but it doesn't help.
The Gradle version used in the project is 7.0.2.
The Android Gradle Plugin version is 7.0.3
Error:

```
One or more issues found when checking AAR metadata values:

The minCompileSdk (32) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-31).
Dependency: androidx.core:core:1.9.0-alpha05.
AAR metadata file: F:\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\3326fc28fcd73f0061a0c85e8c28d621\transformed\core-1.9.0-alpha05\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.

The minCompileSdk (32) specified in a
dependency's AAR metadata (META-INF/com/android/build/gradle/aar-metadata.properties)
is greater than this module's compileSdkVersion (android-31).
Dependency: androidx.core:core-ktx:1.9.0-alpha05.
AAR metadata file: F:\.gradle\caches\transforms-3\7717f94331955bfc5ab8a8990aa9742b\transformed\jetified-core-ktx-1.9.0-alpha05\META-INF\com\android\build\gradle\aar-metadata.properties.
```

Comment: Why not set `compileSdk 32` ...or use stable versions??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have worked this option(I am not sure it is good or bad approach)

1. Add to `android/app/build gradle` dependencies {implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'}
2. Add to `android/build gradle` => `compileSdkVersion = 32`
3. Don't forget to clean `cd android &&./gradlew clean` gradlew

Answer (score 0):

In my case i upgrade my  androidx.core:core-ktx to "androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0" and that fixed the issue

Comment: I have the `core-ktx` version already `1.8.0`, but it doesn't help